# Symfony 2 set background image using CSS

Tags: css, symfony

I want to put a background image for a menu in symfony. But I can't figure out how to do it. 
I managed to style a lot of things already, but not to add a background from css.
This is my project `src` folder with the background style that I am trying to create:
[image: Project structure]

What is the correct path for Symfony to know where is the image? I have tried multiple things and nothing works for me.
THX

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should store your images in the bundle folder.

```
src/MyBundle/Resources/public/images
```

and your css in

```
src/MyBundle/Resources/public/css
```

since only **web** folder is accesible from outside you should use the command

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

this will now create the links for the **web** folder as

```
web/bundles/Project_name/css
web/bundles/Project_name/images
```

So your relative path for the image would be as

```
.header{
    background-image: url("../images/mainlogo.gif");
}
```

And in twig you should use asset() function to link your styles:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmeweb/css/yourstylesheet.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

you can find complete documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets)

Comment: Thank you, `app/console assets:install web --symlink` this was exactly what I needed