# Symfony 3 set background image using CSS

Tags: css, background-image, symfony

The answer provided by "[Symfony 2 set background image using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447339/symfony-2-set-background-image-using-css)" doesn't work in Symfony 3 any more. So I ask the very same question for the next version:

I want to put a background image from CSS, how can I do that?

**What I tried:**

```
/* src/SiteBundle/Resources/public/css/style.css */
#element {
  background: url('../images/image.jpg');
}
```

With an image located at `src/SiteBundle/Resources/public/images/image.jpg`.

Assets are correctly installed with `console asset:install --symlink`, all green to go.

Assetic is manually installed with composer.

CSS is loaded with:

```
<!-- app/Resources/views/base.html.twig -->
{% stylesheets '@SiteBundle/Resources/public/css/*.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

**What I got:**

When I look at my browser inspector, it tells me that the css property is

```
background: url('../../Resources/public/images/image.jpg')
```

which is obviously not working.

**What I tried to fix it:**

I tried changing the CSS background property to `url('images/image.jpg')`, knowing it wouldn't work but to figure out how it handles the links.

The browser inspector told me the link was now `url('../../Resources/public/css/images/image.jpg')`, telling me there is no way I can change the `../../Resources/public/` part.

**How am I supposed to to it correctly?**

Bonus question you should ask yourself before answering: will your answer work when I switch from `dev` to `prod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using the cssrewrite filter, don't refer to your CSS files using the @AppBundle syntax.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter

also:

> Best Practice:
>
> Store your assets in the web/ directory.

So you probably should use:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/site/css/*.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Is this work for both `prod` and `dev`? I really don't know since i'm using gulp to manage assets.

Comment: Thanks, I just found exactly the same answer, I tried it a few seconds before reading your answer and it works! ;-)